# Apache Ignite move data from one cluster to different cluster

Tags: caching, cluster-computing, ignite, gridgain

How to move Ignite cached data from one cluster to other cluster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy your persistence files. By default, they're stored in the working directory - `${IGNITE_HOME}/work`. Copy that directory from the nodes of the first cluster to the nodes of the second.
Note that you need to have the same number of nodes and the same configuration for this to work.

Comment: is there any other way or standard way to do the same?

Comment: @Sandy Not in Apache Ignite. GridGain Ultimate Edition has Snapshot Utility though - with that you can create a snapshot of the database, and then restore from the snapshot on another cluster.